# Unable to play videos from server in android application

Tags: android, android-studio, video

Hello everyone i want to store some videos on a server and then play it in an android application and i have following questions.
1)which server should i use to store videos?
2)how to play the videos one after another in an android application?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use Cloudinary Api for Storing the videos in the server . And you connect with the server using Web services (php).!

Comment: Just go through their portal - cloudinary.com ..! .They are providing excellent support.!

Comment: okay thanks soo much but why do i need a webservice to upload videos? cant i just upload them directly from my android device?